# How can I save my lavender?

Tags: lavender

This lavender was somewhat dry (although still green) when I bought it in a supermarket one week ago. I put it in a bigger pot and watered it, but it's not getting better. The soil is still moist, so I stopped watering it.

Is there still any chance to save it and if so, what can I do?

[image: plant]

Comment: Keep it in the shades for now, and keep the soil moist and wait... Hope it will recover, all you can do is wait and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you touched the roots, so the plant need some time to restore.

Additionally, "Supermarket" usually have plant in shadow (most of the time). It is possible that now it is receiving too much sun (and suddenly). Ideally you should let the plant to adapt slowly (e.g. to put them in half shadow for a week or so (especially in mid summer).

I think you should just wait, and the plant should return to original form.

A small trick: you can spray some water to the leaves: this will get some water direct to leaves, so it will not dry out, it will not damage roots with over-watering. Just few times, before the plant restore. It should really use roots, but on short term, until it regenerate the tips of roots (and with hot weather) this could speed up the process.

Comment: Yes, I had to break some roots while repotting it. And you are right, the plant was stored inside and not watered at all, so it might be stressed now because of the sun and a lot of water.
Thank you for the advice! I hope it recovers.